# Query with left join in linq

Tags: vb.net, linq

Hello I 'm trying to do a query in linq but I think I need some help...

I have two table: langAvailable and Translations
I want a 'line' even if theres no translation recorded

For instance:

```
           LangId: 1  TranslationID:10  Translation: Hello
           LangId: 2  TranslationID:10  Translation: Bonjour
           LangId: 1  TranslationID:11  Translation: Thanks
           LangId: 2  TranslationID:11  Translation:
```

Here's what I do:

```
 Dim query = From c In db.LangAvailable _
             Join o In db.Translate On c.ID_Lang Equals o.Lang_ID _
             Where o.TranslationID = 243 _
             Select New With {c.LangId, o.Translation}
```

This only give me one record if there s no translation in the translate table...
Any idea how I can get that?

Thanx

Answer (score 1):

You can use Group Join to do what you're trying to do. Try this:

```
Dim query = From c In db.LangAvailable _
                Group Join o In db.Translate On c.ID_Lang Equals o.Lang_ID Into Group _
                From o In Group.DefaultIfEmpty() _
                Where o.TranslationId = 243 _
                Select LangId = c.ID_Lang, Translation = If(o.Translation Is Nothing, Nothing, o.Translation)
```